# Overwrite textfile when using file writer append in android

Tags: android, text-files, filestream

I want my app to create a folder in sd card and place the output text file there, for example : mnt/sdcard/myfolder/textfile_name. I've successfully implemented the method of getAbsolutePath, but I find a problem with the text file, if I write 5 lines in the first file then in the next file I write less then 5 lines, the last line in the first file will appear in the second file. I use append command in my app. How do I write it without appending the last one. These are my code

```
public void simpan(View v)
{
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd_MM_yy_HH_mm_ss");
    String time = sdf.format(new Date());
    generate("Transaction " + time.toString() + ".txt");
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Record Saved to /mnt/sdCard/Soto Betawi/" + time.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

private static void generate(String file_name)
{
    try
    {
        File root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        File dir = new File(root.getAbsolutePath() + "/Soto Betawi");
        dir.mkdirs();
        File newfile = new File(dir, file_name);
        FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(newfile);
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yy HH:mm:ss");
        String time = sdf.format(new Date());
        writer.append("Soto Betawi Asli\n");
        writer.append("Haji HUSEN\n");
        writer.append("Jalan Padang Panjang No. 6C\n");
        writer.append("Manggarai, Jakarta Selatan\n\n");
        writer.append("Transaction time : " + time + "\n");
        writer.append("-------------------------------------------------\n");
        writer.append("Menu\t\t\tPrice\t\t\tQuantity\n");
        writer.append("-------------------------------------------------\n");
        writer.append(value1 + "\t\t" + hrg1 + "\t\t" + qty1.getText().toString() + "\n");
        writer.append(value2 + "\t\t" + hrg2 + "\t\t"+ qty2.getText().toString() + "\n");
        writer.append(value3 + "\t\t" + hrg3 + "\t\t" + qty3.getText().toString() + "\n");
        writer.append(value4 + "\t\t" + hrg4 + "\t\t" + qty4.getText().toString() + "\n");
        writer.append(value5 + "\t\t" + hrg5 + "\t\t" + qty5.getText().toString() + "\n");
        writer.append(value6 + "\t\t" + hrg6 + "\t\t" + qty6.getText().toString() + "\n");
        writer.append(value7 + "\t\t" + hrg7 + "\t\t" + qty7.getText().toString() + "\n");
        writer.append(value8 + "\t\t" + hrg8 + "\t\t" + qty8.getText().toString() + "\n");
        writer.append(value9 + "\t\t" + hrg9 + "\t\t" + qty9.getText().toString() + "\n");
        writer.append(value10 + "\t\t" + hrg10 + "\t\t" + qty10.getText().toString() + "\n\n");
        writer.append("Total Pay : Rp. " + hasil);
        writer.flush();
        writer.close();
    }
    catch(IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

```
new FileWriter(newFile);
```

Creates a file for (over-)writing. You need to use

```
new FileWriter(newFile, true);
```

to open it in append mode.

Answer (score 0):

Change the constructor your using for the FileWriter.

Change: FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(newfile);
To: FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(newfile, true);

Answer (score 0):

```
 FileWriter fWriter;
            try{
                 fWriter = new FileWriter(“\sdcard\yourfilename.txt”);
                 fWriter.write(yourString);
                 fWriter.flush();
                 fWriter.close();
             }catch(Exception e){
                      e.printStackTrace();
             }
```

> The flush() and close() calls are important here, and also make sure
>   that the “sdcard” is mounted